# Issue with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to flexbox and I created the following in order to have a top-navigation, with three columns below the top-navigation. When I open my HTML file the top-navigation is `80px` tall but the three columns are only 50%, less the `80px` for the header. I don't understand what is going on? Should the three columns not just fill in the difference?

```css
body {
  font: 24px Helvetica;
  background: #999999;
}
.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.top-navigation {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  background: #cc2936;

}
.left-sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  flexgrow: 1;
}
.main-outlet {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
  flexgrow: 1;

}
.right-sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  background: #dcdcdc;
  flexgrow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="box top-navigation"></div>
  <div class="box left-sidebar"></div>
  <div class="box main-outlet"></div>
  <div class="box right-sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change your layout a little bit. You can then set the wrapping div to have `flex-direction: column` and `align-content: stretch`to the three columns like this:

```css
body {
  font: 24px Helvetica;
  background: #999999;
  margin: 0;
}
.layout {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: stretch;
}
.top-navigation {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  background: #cc2936;

}
.left-sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  background: #dcdcdc;
}
.main-outlet {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.right-sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  background: #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box top-navigation"></div>
<div class="layout">
  <div class="box left-sidebar"></div>
  <div class="box main-outlet"></div>
  <div class="box right-sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The issue I had with that is using 100vh it used 100% of the vh and then added the 80px for the header, which caused the page to have to scroll. I believe I have solved it by creating another flexbox for the 3 columns. Will report back once I've tested it.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah that sounds about right that the problem may be occurring because of the facts that you just explained in detail. I was not properly understanding your problem I guess. Hopefully you get it sorted out :)

Comment: The problem with the scroll (there are not 80px) is the margin that has the body by default. With `body{margin:0;}`  the scroll disappears.